# SSH denied after messing with fstab

Tags: ssh, fstab

**Goal:** repartition one big 5TB `/home` partion into separate partitions on a remote Ubuntu server.

**Approach:** I took a backup of `/home`, then erased the partition in gparted and created new partitions, including `/home` and `/home/username` (`/home` for 2-3 users and a special partition for my own user).

I then mounted the partitions from the terminal and copied the home backup back into `/home`, and edited the `fstab` file, which I suspect went wrong as it is the first time I play around with partitions in Linux. I then did a reboot.

**Issue:** I now get connection refused when I try to ssh or when trying to access FTP.

**Question:** Is there a way to fix this without reinstalling? I have no files but i will have to contact the hosting company to perform a reinstall, so I'd prefer to fix it without having to do that.

Comment: the permisison on the`/home` and/or `/home/username` are likely not correct. But if you can't ssh in, you are screwed.

Comment: Since you can't ssh, the only other option is physical access. You should be asking this question to your hosting company. Some provide a dedicated nigh-impossible to break virtual terminal. It's also possible they could hook-up a monitor and keyboard to help you fix whatever happened to your file system. If they aren't any help then I'm afraid as Bok said reinstallation is your only option.

Comment: could you add what happens when you try SSH'ing with verbose output (e.g. the output of `ssh -v USER@123.456.7.8`)? - if any sensitive stuff (such as passwords & keys, IP addresses/usernames you don't want people to know about...) is it them make sure to modify it to hide/remove it. The disk layout and contents of the `fstab` file may help as well.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling the system. I think solsTiCe is right, i forgot to make permissions on the new /home folder structure.... Rookie mistake, but i sure learned my lesson :D Thanks for the inputs guys

Comment: @Wilf - connection refused by the host, very early in the connection attempt - it doesn't get anywhere basically.

Answer (score 0):

I am equally looking for an answer to this as SSH / FTP is not functional after editing fstab which was on an SD card. What I needed to do to get SSH / FTP login to work was:

1. I copied an image of Ubuntu 18.04 to a thumb drive and used that to boot my "Windows" laptop into Ubuntu using the thumb drive.
2. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> at boot time to select start-up options.
3. Once in Ubuntu I put the SD card into an "ANKER" brand multi-card reader to USB and accessed the SD card through "rootfs".
4. Once I was at the `/etc/fstab` file, I used

   ```
   sudo nano fstab
   ```

   to comment out the line I previously entered that corrupted SSH / FTP login. I saved the edit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, yes, enter) and rebooted my original machine and have access to SSH / FTP.

So to me, that means fstab is a culprit if it is not edited correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar situation here... Virtual machine, setup with two ssh accessible accounts and a webserver.  Added a 1TB drive to the machine, had to reboot to see the drive, sshed in to get it setup, mounted as /dev/sdc1 at /mnt/sdc1, formatted ext4, everything was working - logged out and back in via ssh as both users several times, then edited the fstab to add it to the bottom of the list:

/dev/sdc1 /mnt/sdc1 ext4 rw 0 2

did another reboot and I couldn't get in via ssh anymore: Connection refused.  both accounts.  Waited for a long while thinking maybe it was fsck ing the new 1TB but, there weren't any files on it yet.  Finally pinged it, and it's responding, website is all there and the wiki on the website accepts new edits, but... still Connection refused on port 22 when trying to ssh in as any user.  Predictably: scp also refuses connection.

I can, eventually, get into the VM controls and start the VM from a boot disk then mount the sda1 partition and put /etc/fstab back where it came from, but... why am I here?  How do I eventually fix this so I have my 1TB drive mounting automatically at start *and* ssh access too?

Comment: So, for me, editing /etc/fstab was a coincidence - putting it back did not fix the problem. 

What I found was: the ssh service was failing to start up (server hadn't been restarted in years...), and traced that to a line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config specifying (roughly) PublicKeyTypes +ssh_rsa , commenting that line out permitted the service to load at startup and now it seems O.K.